# Evaluating Surface Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I've been told that surface integrals can be evaluated through projection by

$$\iint_S f(x,y) \, dS = \iint_R \frac{1}{\| \frac{\mathbf{n}}{\|\mathbf{n}\|} \cdot \mathbf k \|  }f(x,y) \,dx\,dy$$

where $\mathbf n $ is normal to the surface $S$ and $R$ is the region $S$ projected onto the $xy-plane$ and $k$ is the unit vector in the $z$ direction

If $f$ can be parameterised

$$\iint_S f(x,y) \, dS = \iint_D f(x(u,v),y(u,v)) \|\mathbf{r_u} \times \mathbf{r_v}\| \, du \, dv$$

where $r(u,v)$ is the parametrised surface with $r_u$ and $r_v$ being its partial derivatives

However I can also use a change of variable so that

$$\iint_R \frac{1}{\| \frac{\mathbf{n}}{\|\mathbf{n}\|} \cdot \mathbf k \|  }f(x,y) \,dx\,dy = \iint_D \frac{1}{\| \frac{\mathbf{n}}{\|\mathbf{n}\|} \cdot \mathbf k \|  }f(x(u,v),y(u,v)) \mid \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} \mid \, du\,dv $$

And so

$$\iint_D \frac{1}{\| \frac{\mathbf{n}}{\|\mathbf{n}\|} \cdot \mathbf k \|  }f(x(u,v),y(u,v)) \mid \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} \mid \,du\,dv = \iint_D f(x(u,v),y(u,v)) \|\mathbf{r_u} \times \mathbf{r_v}\|\,du\,dv $$

Meaning that

$$\frac{1}{\| \frac{\mathbf{n}}{\|\mathbf{n}\|} \cdot \mathbf k \|}\times \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} = \|\mathbf{r_u} \times \mathbf{r_v}\|$$

Is this correct? And if so, how can you show that they are equal? Thanks

Also is there a way to format unit vectors using latex? I tried searching on the MathJaX help but was unable to find anything haha